# Kendo Grid Filter Using YYYY-MM date format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My problem here is described as follows: 
I want to filter out kendo grid results by months (**BudgetItemStartDate** field in my case) with "**YYYY-MM**" format. The filter is working fine when I select the first day in the desired month! (when depth and start is set as: "month", but this is not the case that i want). My need is to filter out the results just selecting the month. I still get empty results when a month is being selected.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ServiceCostReportDTO>()
     .Name("ServiceCostReportListGrid")
     .Columns(cols =>
     {
      ...
      cols.Bound(m => m.BudgetItemStartDate)
          .Title("Budget Item Start Date")
          .Format("{0:yyyy-MM}")
          .Width(130)
          .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "background-color: Beige;" })
          .Filterable(f => f.Cell(c => c.Template("dateFilter")));
      ...
     }
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(true)
    .PageSize(AppSession.Current.GetParameterValue<int>(AppConstants.ConfigParameters_PageSize))
    .Read(read => read.Action("ReadServiceCostReportList", "ServiceCostReport").Data("getFilterValues"))
    )
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .AutoBind(true) //This will not automatically call the read action
    .Excel(excel => excel
        .FileName("Service_Cost_Report_" + DateTime.Now.Year + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month + "_" + DateTime.Now.Day + "_" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "_" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "_" + DateTime.Now.Second + ".xlsx")
        .AllPages(true)
        .Filterable(true)
        .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "ExcelExport"))
    )
    .ToolBar(t =>
    {
        //t.Template("<a class='k-button' onclick='excelExport()' href='#'><span class='k-icon k-i-excel'></span>Export to Excel</a>");
        t.Excel();
    })
    .ColumnMenu(x => {
        x.Sortable(true);
        x.Filterable(true);
    })
    .Events(e => {
        e.DataBound("resizeGrid");
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Pageable()
    .Editable(editing => editing.Enabled(false))
    .Scrollable(cfg => cfg.Height("auto"))
    //.Groupable()
    .Filterable(ftb =>
    {
        ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row);
        ftb.Messages(m => m.IsFalse("No"));
        ftb.Messages(m => m.IsTrue("Yes"));
    })
```

Kendo date time picker template

```
   function dateFilter(e) {
        e.element.kendoDatePicker({
           depth: "year",
           start: "year",
           format: "yyyy-MM",
           parseFormat: "yyyy-MM",
       })
   }
```

In my case, date with YYYY-MM format are being stored in database as strings. So, when I retrieve the data from db, my Model looks like this

```
public class ServiceCostReportDTO
{
  ...
  public string BudgetSplitStartDateString {get; set;}
  public DateTime? BudgetSplitStartDate
  {
        get
        {
            if (BudgetSplitStartDateString != null)
                return new DateTime(int.Parse(BudgetSplitStartDateString.Substring(0, 4)), int.Parse(BudgetSplitStartDateString.Substring(5, 2)), 1);
            else
                return null;
            //return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(new DateTime(int.Parse(StartDateString.Substring(0, 4)), int.Parse(StartDateString.Substring(5, 2)), 1));
        }
        set 
        {
            if (BudgetSplitStartDate != null)
            {
                BudgetSplitStartDateString = value.GetValueOrDefault().Year.ToString() + "-" + value.GetValueOrDefault().Month.ToString("0#");
            }
            else
            {
                BudgetSplitStartDateString = null;
            }
        }
    }
   ...
  }
```

I tried so many workarounds but i didn't manage to get a solution for this issue. Is there anyone who could help me? Thanks!

[Day picker Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmyyA.png)

[Results of day picker Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjqFl.png)

[Month picker - This is what I really want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Gk8.png)

[Not get results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QIRV.png)

Comment: So you want to select a start date from the grid and return related information to the same grid?

Comment: Could you provide an example, whether a screenshot or a demo table somewhere?

Comment: @noobed, I attached 4 screenshots to this post. Thanks.

Comment: @David From the screenshots what I can see is the date is being parsed (filtered) in different format. That might be causing the problem.